# Solution blows up when using Runge-Kutta to solve simultaneous ODEs for liquid film equations

Tags: matlab, fluid-dynamics, runge-kutta

This is a continuation of a problem I asked over at [physics exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154570/can-i-use-runge-kutta-to-solve-these-equations) and [math exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078136/can-i-use-runge-kutta-to-solve-these-two-equations).  Basically I have two ODEs that I am solving in order to calculate the radial and tangential velocity of liquid dispensed on the center of a disk rotating at rate of $\omega$. $u_m$ is the average flow velocity in the $r$-direction, and the $v_m$ is the average flow velocity in the $\theta$-direction.  They are defined as

$$u_m(r)=\frac{1}{h(r)}\int_0^{h(r)}u(r,z)\,dz$$

$$v_m(r)=\frac{1}{h(r)}\int_0^{h(r)}v(r,z)\,dz$$

Where $h(r)$ is the height of the liquid film on the spinning disk.  Using the continuity equation, the height of the film is

$$h(r)=\frac{Q}{2\pi\,r\,u_m}$$

Where $Q$ is the flow rate of liquid onto the spinning disk.  Using appropriate boundary conditions of no-slip at $z=0$ and no shear at $z=h(r)$, the velocities $u$ and $v$ are:

$$u(r,z)=3u_m\left[ \frac{z}{h}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z}{h} \right)^2 \right]$$

$$v(r,z)=r\,\omega+\frac{3}{2}(r\,\omega- v_m)\left[\left(\frac{z}{h} \right)^2 -2 \frac{z}{h}\right]$$

Then taking the Navier Stokes equations in cylindrical coordinates and assuming that $\partial P/\partial r=0$, the remaining relevant terms are then

$$u\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}-\frac{v^2}{r}=\nu \left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} \right)$$

$$u\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}+\frac{vu}{r}=\nu \left(\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial z^2} \right)$$

Then I substitute $u(r,z)$ and $v(r,z)$ into the N-S equations, integrate them from $0$ to $h(r)$ in the $z$-direction, and then substitute $h(r)$ in terms of $Q$ using the equation above.  This then gives me two coupled ODEs where $u_m$ and $v_m$ are the dependent variables and $r$ is the independent variable.  The ODEs are

$$69ru_m\frac{du_m}{dr}=8r^2\omega^2-16r\omega v-21{u_m}^2+48{v_m}^2-\frac{480\pi^2\nu r^3{u_m}^3}{Q^2}$$

$$21r(v_m-r\omega)\frac{du_m}{dr}+48ru\frac{dv_m}{dr}=-69u_m v_m+37r\omega u_m+\frac{480\pi^2\nu r^3(v_m-r\omega){u_m}^2}{Q^2}$$

To solve these equations I rearranged them in matrix form:

$$\textbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}69\,r\,u_m & 0\\ 21(r\,v_m-r^2\omega) & 48\,r\,u_m \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\textbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix}u_m \\ v_m \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\textbf{f}=\begin{bmatrix} 8\,r^2\omega^2-16\,r\,\omega\,v_m-21{u_m}^2+48{v_m}^2-\frac{480\pi^2\nu}{Q^2}r^3{u_m}^3 \\ -69\,u_m\,v_m+37\,r\,\omega\,u_m-\frac{480\pi^2\nu}{Q^2}r^3{u_m}^2(v_m-r\,\omega) \end{bmatrix}$$

Then the equations are of the form

$$\textbf{A} \frac{d \textbf{u}}{dr}=\textbf{f}$$

I can rearrange this as

$$\frac{d \textbf{u}}{dr}=\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{f}$$

And solve it using a Runge-Kutta method.  I have tried solving it using the following code in MATLAB:

```
function output = improvedPigford(flow,spin)
if nargin<2
    spin = 75;          % [RPM]
end
if nargin<1
    flow = 935;         % [mL/min]
end

w = spin*pi*2/60;       % rotation of wafer [rad/s]
d = 0.002;              %diameter of injection nozzle [m]

r0 = 0.5*d;             % begin solving here [m]
q = flow/(100^3*60);    % volumetric flow rate of liquid [m^3/s]
kv = 8.926780E-07;      % kinematic viscosity of water @ 25C [m^2/s]
u0 = q/(pi*r0^2);       % initial r-velocity (assume same as nozzle velocity) [m/s]
v0 = 0;                 % initial theta-velocity [m/s]

%% solve improved Pigford model
rRange = [r0 0.1];
initCond = [u0 v0];

options = odeset('Stats','on','RelTol',1e-6,'MStateDependence','strong');
dudr = @(r,u) improvedModel(r,u,q,kv,w);
sol = ode15s(dudr,rRange,initCond,options);
r = sol.x;
u = sol.y(1,:);
v = sol.y(2,:);
h = q./(2*pi*r.*u);

%% plot section
figure(1);clf;
plot(r*1000,u,'r-',r*1000,v,'b-');
xlabel('Radius (mm)');
ylabel('Fluid Velocity (m/s)');

%% output section
output=[r,u,v,h];

end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
function dudr = improvedModel(r,u,q,kv,w)
%{
Function is of the form A*u=f, so u=inv(A)*f
%}

A = [69*r*u(1), 0; 21*r*(u(2)-r*w), 48*r*u(1)];
f = [8*r^2*w^2 - 16*r*w*u(2) - 21*u(1)^2 + 48*u(2)^2 - (480*pi^2*kv*r^3*u(1)^3)/q^2;...
    -69*u(1)*u(2) + 37*r*w*u(1) + (480*pi^2*kv*r^3*u(1)^2*(u(2)-r*w))/q^2];
dudr = A\f;
end
```

However when I run this code the solution always blows up at about %r=0.0441%, no matter which RK function I use: ode45, ode23, ode113, ode15s, ode23s, ode23t, or ode23tb.  The place where the solution blows up does change when I change the parameters like flow rate, spin speed, viscosity, etc., but it does always blow up.

Am I perhaps doing something wrong in my implementation of the Runge-Kutta method in MATLAB, or is it possible that the equations are simply ill-posed?  Maybe there is simply a singularity at the location where it blows up or something?  I've checked the integration of the N-S equations several times using symbolic mathematics software, and I'm fairly confident that I did it correctly.  Otherwise though I'm kind of out of ideas of what to look at next.  Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

### Update

Following the suggestion of @Geoff Oxberry I changed the MATLAB formulation to include the possibility that the mass matrix $\textbf{A}$ may be singular.  Doing that the new code is this:

```
function output = improvedPigford(flow,spin)
if nargin<2
    spin = 200;         % [RPM]
end
if nargin<1
    flow = 1000;        % [mL/min]
end

w = spin*pi*2/60;       % rotation of wafer [rad/s]
d = 0.002;              %diameter of injection nozzle [m]

r0 = 0.5*d;             % begin solving here [m]
q = flow/(100^3*60);    % volumetric flow rate of liquid [m^3/s]
kv = 8.926780E-07;      % kinematic viscosity of water @ 25C [m^2/s]
u0 = q/(pi*r0^2);       % initial r-velocity (assume same as nozzle velocity) [m/s]
v0 = 0;                 % initial theta-velocity [m/s]

%% solve improved Pigford model
rRange = [r0 0.1];
initCond = [u0 v0];

dudr = @(r,u) improvedModel(r,u,q,kv,w);
M = @(r,u) massMatrix(r,u,w);
options = odeset('Stats','on','RelTol',1e-6,'Mass',M);
sol = ode15s(dudr,rRange,initCond,options);
r = sol.x;
u = sol.y(1,:);
v = sol.y(2,:);
h = q./(2*pi*r.*u);

%% plot section
figure(1);clf;
plot(r*1000,u,'r-',r*1000,v,'b-');
xlabel('Radius (mm)');
ylabel('Fluid Velocity (m/s)');

%% output section
output=[r,u,v,h];

end

function f = improvedModel(r,u,q,kv,w)
%{
Function is of the form M*u'=f
%}
f = [8*r^2*w^2 - 16*r*w*u(2) - 21*u(1)^2 + 48*u(2)^2 - (480*pi^2*kv*r^3*u(1)^3)/q^2;...
    -69*u(1)*u(2) + 37*r*w*u(1) + (480*pi^2*kv*r^3*u(1)^2*(u(2)-r*w))/q^2];
end

function M = massMatrix(r,u,w)
%{
Function calculates the mass matrix M for M*u'=f
%}
M = [69*r*u(1), 0; 21*r*(u(2)-r*w), 48*r*u(1)];
end
```

However, the result is the same: the solution still blows up at the same location.

### Update 2

As @Kirill asked, I am showing a plot of what the solution looks like when it blows up.

[image: Image of blown-up solution]

$v_m$ goes to $-\infty$, while $u_m$ goes to $+\infty$.  What makes me suspicious that something may be wrong is the fact that due to boundary conditions on $v(r,z)$ [$v=r\,\omega$ @ $z=0$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}=0$ @ $z=h(r)$], $v_m$ should almost certainly be positive.  @Kirill found a sign discrepancy between my derivation and his derivation done using Mathematica, so I will be checking my derivation again, then getting back with my results.

### Update 3

I went over the calculations *again*, and I think I did have a sign error as @Kirill postulated.  After working through derivation one more time, I ended up with the following equations:

$$69r\,u_m\frac{du_m}{dr}=8r^2\omega^2-16r\omega v_m-21{u_m}^2+48{v_m}^2-\frac{480\pi^2\nu r^3{u_m}^3}{Q^2}$$

$$21r(v_m-r\omega)\frac{du_m}{dr}+48r\,u_m\frac{dv_m}{dr}=-69u_m v_m+37r\omega u_m-\frac{480\pi^2\nu r^3(v_m-r\omega){u_m}^2}{Q^2}$$

This is equivalent to the equations that @Kirill obtained doing the derivation in Mathematica.  When solving this system of equations (using the above code but with the corrected term) I get the following plots for $u_m$ and $v_m$:

[image: improved model]

This appears to be identical to the plot that @Kirill showed.

For a further comparison, this derivation is an improvement of the Pigford model, which can be found here:

> R.M. Wood and B.E. Watts, "The Flow, Heat, and Mass Transfer
>   Characteristics of Liquid Films on Rotating Disks", *Trans. Instn
>   Chem. Engrs.*, Vol 51, 1973.

The derivation of the Pigford model is identical to mine, except that the final integration $\int_0^h(r) dz$ is simply skipped over, with the $u(r,z)$ and $v(r,z)$ simply being replaced by $u_m(r)$ and $v_m(r)$, with an $O(1)$ correction factor added to each equation.  From this the Pigford model equations are:

$$r\,u_m \frac{du_m}{dr}={v_m}^2-\frac{12 K_1 \nu\, \pi^2\,r^3\,{u_m}^3}{Q^2}$$

$$r\,u_m \frac{dv_m}{dr}=-u_m v_m-\frac{12 K_2 \nu\, \pi^2\,r^3\,(v_m-r\,\omega){u_m}^2}{Q^2}$$

If I solve those two equations simultaneously, I get the following solution:

[image: Pigford model]

Which is qualitatively close to the equations that I derived.  For a final comparison, I'll look at the height $h(r)$ calculated by both of the models:

[image: film height comparison]

The shapes of the two curves are a little different, but mostly only differ by a $O(1)$ constant, as one might expect because of the addition of the fitting constants in the Pigford model.

Comment: Is the sign in front of "480" in the 2nd equation correct? (See my answer.)

Comment: Sorry, another thing: *please, please, please* include a plot in your question. There are so many different ways a solution can blow up!

Comment: OK, I'll put in a plot showing how it's blowing up.

Comment: @Kirill, I put up a plot of the blown up results.  I'm still working on checking over the derivation to see if there is a sign error.

Comment: @Kirill was correct in finding the sign error in my derivation.  Thanks everyone for all the help.

Comment: @Darek Can someone please share a hyperlink of the Wood and Watts work referenced above?

Comment: @DKS sure thing.  Here it is:

http://archive.icheme.org/cgi-bin/somsid.cgi?session=119158C&type=header&record=1294

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bearing in mind that I have just a vague idea of what results you are
expecting, I want to point out that I do not get the same ODE system
as you do. I'm using Mathematica.

Using your equations for $h(r)$, $u(r,z)$, $v(r,z)$ and the two NS
equations, the following code generates the ODE system:

```
Module[{uu, vv, h},
 h = q/(2 Pi r u[r]);
 uu = 3 u[r] (z/h - (z/h)^2/2);
 vv = r w + 3/2 (r w - v[r]) ((z/h)^2 - 2 z/h);
 Integrate[
  {uu D[uu, r] - vv^2/r - kv D[uu, z, z],
   uu D[vv, r] + vv uu/r - kv D[vv, z, z]}
  , {z, 0, h}]
 ]
Thread[{0, 0} == (Numerator[Together[#/q]] & /@ %)]
```

$$ 
0=480 \pi ^2 \nu r^3 u(r)^3-8 q^2 r^2 w^2+69 q^2 r u(r) u'(r)+21 q^2 u(r)^2+16 q^2 r w v(r)-48 q^2
   v(r)^2\\
0=-480 \pi ^2 \nu r^4 w u(r)^2+480 \pi ^2 \nu r^3 u(r)^2 v(r)-21 q^2 r^2 w u'(r)+21 q^2 r v(r)
   u'(r)+48 q^2 r u(r) v'(r)+69 q^2 u(r) v(r)-37 q^2 r w u(r)
$$

The only difference seems to be the sign on the "480"-term in the second equation, I get it as "$-$".

Now, if I solve the system of ODEs that you have in the question using Mathematica's `NDSolve`, I also get a blow-up. But if I solve the system I generated above from the same equations, I get the following plot:

[image: Plot]

This looks okay to me, there is no blow-up, although I can't be sure this is right. So
having said all this, are you *absolutely* sure your ODE system is
actually correct?

Here is the ode solver invocation (the commented out sections `(*...*)` are two versions of your ODE system):

```
Module[{
  spin = 75,
  flow = 935,
  w, d, r0, rRange, q, kv, u0, v0, r, u, v
  , slv
  },
 w = spin Pi*2/60;
 d = 0.002;
 r0 = 0.5 d;
 q = flow/(100^3*60);
 kv = 8.926780*^-7;
 u0 = q/(Pi r0^2);
 v0 = 0;
 rRange = {r0, 0.1};
 (*slv=NDSolve[
 Join[{u[r0]==u0,v[r0]==v0},
 Thread[{u'[r],v'[r]}== Inverse[{{69r u[r],0},{21r (v[r]-r w),48r \
u[r]}}]
 .{8*r^2*w^2-16*r*w*v[r]-21*u[r]^2+48*v[r]^2-(480*Pi^2*kv*r^3*u[r]^3)/\
q^2,-69*u[r]*v[r]+37*r*w*u[r]+(480*Pi^2*kv*r^3*u[r]^2*(v[r]-r*w))/q^2}\
]]
 ,{u,v},{r,r0,rRange[[2]]}];*)
 (*slv=NDSolve[{
 69r u[r]u'[r]==8r^2w^2-16r w v[r]-21u[r]^2+48 v[r]^2-480Pi^2 kv \
r^3u[r]^3/q^2,
 21r (v[r]-r w)u'[r]+48 r u[r] v'[r]==-69 u[r]v[r]+37r w u[r]+480Pi^2 \
kv r^3(v[r]-r w)u[r]^2/q^2,
 u[r0]==u0,
 v[r0]==v0
 },{u,v},{r,r0,rRange[[2]]}];*)
 slv = NDSolve[{
    0 == -8 q^2 r^2 w^2 + 21 q^2 u[r]^2 + 480 kv \[Pi]^2 r^3 u[r]^3 + 
      16 q^2 r w v[r] - 48 q^2 v[r]^2 + 69 q^2 r u[r] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["u", "\[Prime]",
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r], 
    0 == -37 q^2 r w u[r] - 480 kv \[Pi]^2 r^4 w u[r]^2 + 
      69 q^2 u[r] v[r] + 480 kv \[Pi]^2 r^3 u[r]^2 v[r] - 21 q^2 r^2 w 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["u", "\[Prime]",
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r] + 21 q^2 r v[r] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["u", "\[Prime]",
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r] + 48 q^2 r u[r] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["v", "\[Prime]",
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r],
    u[r0] == u0,
    v[r0] == v0
    }, {u, v}, {r, r0, rRange[[2]]}];
 If[Head[slv] =!= NDSolve, slv = slv[[1]], Abort[]];
 Print@Plot[Evaluate[{u[r], v[r]} /. slv], {r, r0, rRange[[2]]}]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this.  For the analytical derivation Mathematica is certainly much easier to work with than MATLAB.  I'll check over my analysis again and get back to you.

Comment: @Derek It's no problem, I actually like this question. Even if my answer is wrong, scientific computing is full of sign errors.

Comment: It looks like it was a sign error after all.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I can think of with your derivation is the $\mathbf{A}$ term. If at any point that term fails to be invertible, then your derivation is no longer valid. You should see the the value of $\mathbf{A}$ is at your singularity, and if it is still invertible.

Another way to diagnose this problem would be to use a DAE solver on $\textbf{A} \frac{d \textbf{u}}{dr}=\textbf{f}$ directly, instead of inverting $\mathbf{A}$; you could use `ode15i` for this purpose. If the DAE solver works, then there's a good chance singularity of $\mathbf{A}$ is to blame; if not, then you'll have to look for other alternative solutions.

EDIT: Here are some other possible causes of the behavior you're seeing that you may want to investigate:

- *Is there a numerical stability issue with the integration methods you're using?* Based on what you've said, it seems a little unlikely; you've tried methods that are generally geared toward stiff problems (`ode15s`: NDF/BDF methods, `ode23s`: Rosenbrock methods, `ode23tb`: TR-BDF2) and nonstiff problems (`ode45` & `ode23`: explicit Runge-Kutta). Neither seems to help. Sometimes, there are telltale instabilities that can be seen when trying to solve a stiff problem with explicit methods (e.g., sometimes growing oscillations precede the solution blowing up).
- *Is there a scaling issue with units?* One way to diagnose this sort of error would be to look at the conditioning of the linear systems being solved within the implicit ODE (or DAE) solvers (so, `ode15s`, `ode23s`, `ode23tb`, etc.). Poorly conditioned systems also tend to be stiff (even if nondimensionalizing them would yield a nonstiff system), which would explain why nonstiff integrators also blow up. Nondimensionalization usually improves the conditioning in these cases, so you may also try to solve a nondimensionalized version of your problem instead. I'd check scaling next.
- *Is your right-hand side regular enough over the interval of integration?* By that, I mean, is it $k$ times continuously differentiable, where $k$ is greater than or equal to the order of time discretizations you're using? I also doubt that the problems you're seeing are due to derivatives failing to exist, because your right-hand side and mass matrix consist of polynomials.
- *Is there something about the system analytically that causes it to blow up?* I sort of doubt it, but exploring solved test problems in the literature and asymptotics can be helpful here. If there's a test problem in the literature that maps closely to what you're modeling here, you should use it as a benchmark for validation, because it can be helpful in debugging. You could find out that there's a "blow up time" beyond which something about your approximation breaks down.

Comment: I can try that.  DAE solvers on MATLAB use the symbolic math toolbox, correct?  I have that, but mostly only use it for MuPAD...  So try something like [these](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-dae-system-using-matlab-ode-solvers.html) examples?

Comment: I don't believe the DAE solvers use the MATLAB symbolic toolbox.

Comment: I think I found it.  The help documentation for `odeset` has a section **Mass Matrix and DAE Properties** that explains what to do when the mass matrix may be singular.  I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: I reformulated it as a DAE with a possibly singular mass matrix, but it didn't affect the answer.  I put my new code as an update on my original post.